How can we add multiple jwtrules for the same namespace/workloads?
We have a service which acts as a context path for internal services. I am planning to add multiple jwt rules, bbut it is complaining that jwt is not configured, but it works with only one jwt rules.
How can we add multiple jwtrules for the same namespace/workloads?
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata: 
  name: authentication-jwt-token
  namespace: spaceA
spec: 
  jwtRules: 
    - 
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      fromHeaders: 
        - 
          name: Authorization
          prefix: "Bearer "
      issuer: test@test.com
      jwksUri: "http://test/jwks"  
      selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: serviceA
--- 
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata: 
  name: authentication-jwt-token
  namespace: istio-system
spec: 
  jwtRules: 
    - 
      issuer: test@test.com
      jwksUri: "http://test/jwks"
      forwardOriginalToken: true
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway

